# How to loop collection without looping inside each item?

Tags: laravel, loops, collections

I have a collection. For each item I want to add a new attribute [users]. When I loop collection with map function or even if foreach, I notice, the code is looping inside each item. So each atribute from collection item is read. Please look at this following

```
   Log $myCollection: 
    local.INFO: Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 6
                        [name] => AAAAA
                        [code] => D2
                        [component_id] => 5
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 7
                        [name] => BBBB
                        [code] => D1
                        [component_id] => 5
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 47
                        [name] => CCCC
                        [code] => CR7
                        [component_id] => 3
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 48
                        [name] => DDDD
                        [code] => CJ9
                        [component_id] => 3
                    )
            )
    )



    $myCollection->map(function ($item) use($users, $role) {
        $item = Site::findOrFail($item);
        $item->users = $users;
        return $item;
    });
```

I get : 
        SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "AAAA". and I think it is because the code loops on name from each item of myCollection.

How do I fix it, please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `$item` contains each object of the collection so you should use the appropriate key.

```
$myCollection->map(function ($item) use($users, $role) {
   $item = Site::findOrFail($item->id); // or $item['id']
   $item->users = $users;
   return $item;
});
```

Actually now that I looked at it better, you don't need at all to find the item again. So in your closure just having these two lines is enough.

```
$item->users = $users;
return $item;
```